# Are quantities involved in Generalized Ramanujan Conjecture eigenvalues of some unitary operator?

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms, l-functions

If I'm not mistaken, every automorphic L-function $L(s,\pi)$ verifies $\displaystyle{L(s,\pi)=\prod_{p}L_{p}(s,\pi_{p})}$ where $L_{p}(s,\pi_{p})=\displaystyle{\prod_{j=1}^{m}\big(1-\frac{\alpha_{\pi}(p,j)}{p^s}\big)^{-1}}$, and Generalized Ramanujan Conjecture (GRC for short) says that if $\pi$ is an irreducible unitary cuspidal representation of $\mathrm{GL}_{m}(\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}})$ we have $\vert\alpha_{\pi}(p,j)\vert=1$ for all but finitely many primes $p$.

My question is: do we know a pair $(\mathcal{H},A)$ where $\mathcal{H}$ is a Hilbert space and $A$ a unitary automorphism of $\mathcal{H}$ whose quantities $\alpha_{\pi}(p,j)$ are suspected to be eigenvalues?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would guess you can do something with the intertiwner for principal series representation, but I am not sure how that would be achievable. If you drop unitary, you can get the $a_p + \overline{a_p}$ as the trace of the Hecke operators acting on some natural space Hilbertspace times some archimedean component. Since these operators are trace class, they can't be unitary though.

Comment: Ok, thanks for both your comment and editing. I'm gonna think about your suggestion.